# Less than condition in if loop not working - Liquid HTML

Tags: shopify, liquid

In liquid html greater than condition works well in if loop

```
{% assign var1 = product.extended_attributes.inventory | plus: 0 %}
  {% if var1 > 5 %}
    test text
  {% endif %}
```

This condition works. But i want to check for less than condition

```
{% assign var1 = product.extended_attributes.inventory | plus: 0 %}
 {% if var1 < 5 %}
   test text
 {% endif %}
```

This code breaks the liquid html syntax in `<` so this condition not working.

Note: this happens on blueshift email template. Not sure about others.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is an app specific bug. Try this instead

```
{% assign var1 = product.extended_attributes.inventory | plus: 0 %}
 {% unless var1 >= 5 %}
   test text
 {% endunless %}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented same.